# Printing Unicode or Supplementary Character in Java

Tags: java, unicode, type-conversion, export-to-text

I am trying to print a reverse bullet Unicode character to a txt file. I keep looking up information and nothing works. It always prints a question mark character to the file. 
This error I am going to attach is the only way I have seen the symbol produced in java. 
I am sure it can be written to a text file and I have heard stuff about maybe it needs to be converted? 
If anyone knows how to get the reverse bullet to print out to a text file I would greatly appreciate it! 
Here is a picture of the code and the error it gave me...

[image]

Thank you to anyone that knows the answer in advance. I have been searching around online all day and I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1):

To store a string as bytes in a file, Java has to encode that string.

By default, Java uses system encoding, which on Windows is something useless like Windows-1252 or so.

Use `new PrintWriter("tab.txt", "UTF-8")`.

Comment: I tried a lot of different stuff and used that actually. It worked, thank you!